# unable connecting to svn using the svn-spawn node module

Tags: node.js, svn

I was actually checking on connecting to svn repository from javascript using some wrapper, but was unable to find any such js wrapper. So I found this [svn-spawn](https://npmjs.org/package/svn-spawn) node  module which lets us to connect to the svn repo. But I think I am doing something wrong, not sure where and what. Need some pointers on how to go about resolving the error:

the code :

```
var Client = require('svn-spawn');
var client = new Client({
cwd: 'http://support.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/'
});

client.cmd(['checkout'], function(err, data) {
if(!err){

console.log('subcommand done' + data);
}else{
console.log('the erro is '+ err);
}
});
```

the erro that I am getting:

```
the erro is Error: spawn ENOENT

chdir(): No such file or directory

the erro is Error: chdir(): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cwd` argument is not a URL to the remote repository. Rather, it's a local directory name, when you wish your "current directory" to be, as if you invoked `svn` from there. Presumably the directory containing `.svn`.

Comment: So is it possible to checkout the code from public repositories using this or nay other node module? Basically I want to build a middle-ware or interface using which I will display the data in a webpage. This could be done by the SVNKIT library but that's java based, I was looking for something in javascript / nodejs.

Comment: I don't see why not. If you want to checkout then invoke the checkout command, supply the remote repository URL as an argument *to the command* (not to the client), and set the client's `cwd` to a new directory that you create just for that.